# Part of string search and replace in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I wanted to do some regex search on strings and remove that part of the string that matches.

Eg. I have following strings

```
xyz-v1.0.0#
abc-v2.0.0#
def-v1.1.0#
```

So, for such cases, I wanted to remove -v1.0.0#, -v2.0.0# and -v1.1.0# from these strings.

So, for this what regex can I use and how can I remove them in Node JS?

Comment: Can you put the code you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

`.replace(/-.*$/, '')` will check for -{anything} at the end of the string and replace with nothing.

```js
const strs = [
  'xyz-v1.0.0#',
  'abc-v2.0.0#',
  'def-v1.1.0#'
];
const newStrs = strs.map(str => str.replace(/-.*$/, ''));
console.log(newStrs);
```

Comment: You could also use the regular expression `/-v.*$/` to make sure that it is replacing the version at the end of the string.

Comment: there is actually one issue here. say, if string is abc-vxy-v1.0.0#, then it is removing -vxy-v1.0.0#, I only want to remove from last dash(-)

Comment: Okay, you can use this regular expression `/-v\d+\.\d+\.\d+#$/` to match this specific format `-v{number}.{number}.{number}#`. I have to go out now, but i'll think of something better later.

Comment: Yeah this is one way. This is also not always correct, I am thinking if somehow I could detect last dash(-) somehow, that would be best. like instead of .*, restriction on dot(.) to not include dash(-)

Comment: Try adding $ at end of the regular expression, it should only match the end of the string

Comment: No thats not the case. That I already have. Is there any way I could ignore some characters like here other dash(-).

Comment: So this regular expression `/-v(\d+\.?){3}#$/` worked for me in https://repl.it/NcE6. If you have some case it is not working you could list it so I could see what is going on.